# Create table using jQuery and .append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create table that looks like this using append jQuery. Below is my try.

```
aside = $("#tabaside");
var tr = $("<tr>");
var td = $("<td>");

for (var i = 0; i < filmidata.arr.length; i++) {
  $(aside).append(tr);
  $(tr).append(td).text("text");
  $(tr).append(td).text("text");
  $(tr).append(td).text("text");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Every `append` call appends the same element, causing nothing additional to be appended. You have to create something new in every iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a new `tr` for each row, and a new `td` for each cell. `.append()` doesn't make copies, it just keeps reusing the same DOM element.

You can use a nested loop to repeat the code for the cells.

```js
const aside = $("#tabaside");
for (var i = 0; i < filmidata.arr.length; i++) {
  let tr = $("<tr>");
  $(aside).append(tr);
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    $(tr).append($("<td>", {
      text: "text"
    }));
  }
}
```